# ImportError: cannot import name 'Employees' from 'EmployeeApp.models'

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I am pretty new to Building an application with Django Framework, Python and Flask. I tried to import reference some module and i receive this error. Can someone help?
My code is below

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from EmployeeApp.models import Departments,Employees
from EmployeeApp.serializers import DepartmentSerializer,EmployeeSerializer
```

The error that i saw

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Employees' from 'EmployeeApp.models'(/path/to/the/file.py)
```

rest_framework.parsers could not be resolved. Also, it seem that the line of the Employees in line 6 & EmployeeSerializer in line 7 are not able to be imported.

Please let me know if you need further information.

I expected running python manage.py runserver to pass successfully but with the failed error above, it gives me worries.

Models.py

```
class Employees(models.Model):
EmployeeId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
Department = models.CharField(max_length=500)
DateOfJoining = models.DateField()
PhotoFileName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Comment: _Please let me know if you need further information_ Yes, we need to see `EmployeeApp/models.py`

Comment: Maybe the model class name is `Employee` rather than `Employees`?  How did you declare it in the "models.py" file?  Normally a class name should be descriptive of a single instance of the class.  It will be singular unless the class itself denotes a collection.

Comment: If you are using vscode in windows, then you may need to start the import path from the dir that you have currently opened.

Comment: Yes, @Stephen C. yes in the models.py, Employees was referenced as Employee, so i changed it and it worked.

Comment: I think you should have changed the import to match the class, not the other way around.  But ... either will work.

Comment: Thank you stephen. Employees was also referenced in other model. So the Employees solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this imports if you are in same app directory

```
from .models import Departments,Employees
from .serializers import DepartmentSerializer,EmployeeSerializer
```